# Give specific instances that proves: "For when I am weak, then I am Strong" - 2 Corinthians 12:9-10

Tags: 2-corinthians

Give specific instances that prove: "For when I am weak, then I am Strong" - 2 Corinthians 12:9-10. It seems self-contradictory, but I do agree with it. I am curious about other examples that prove this.

Another thing, what does it really mean?

Comment: "For the word of the cross is folly to those who are perishing, but to us who are being saved it is the power of God” (1 Cor 1:18). Christ crucified is the ultimate example of strength clothed in weakness. The cross is the embodiment of human weakness – pain, death, rejection, abandonment, failure and affliction (cf Is 53:1-12). But it also manifests the power of God’s redeeming love (Jn 15:13, Rom 5:8). Love entails vulnerability, therein lies its power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the meaning, look at the context:

> 7 So to keep me from becoming conceited because of the surpassing greatness of the revelations, a thorn was given me in the flesh, a messenger of Satan to harass me, to keep me from becoming conceited. 8 Three times I pleaded with the Lord about this, that it should leave me. 9 But he said to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for my power is made perfect in weakness.” Therefore I will boast all the more gladly of my weaknesses, so that the power of Christ may rest upon me. 10 For the sake of Christ, then, I am content with weaknesses, insults, hardships, persecutions, and calamities. For when I am weak, then I am strong.
> (2 Cor. 12:7–10, ESV)

If Paul were dependent on his own strength, he would be limited by the human limitations of human ability.  By his weakness causing him to depend on Christ, his strength was no longer his, but God's, and was limited only by God's will.  Thus, he could accomplish whatever God desired.

Comment: Excellent answer.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

That's actualy a great question...and the funny thing is I happened to see it as I was having a bit of an emotional breakdown in my truck this morning. And the words that came to me were...'My strength is made perfect in weakness" (2Cor 7)...and then a bit later I saw your question on the group. There's  a comforting and enduring  strength that comes from Godly sorrow, because our prayers and supplications are actualy a sign of weakness...I believe it moves God to compassion and His Spirit  works within the Believer, perfectly strengthening them.

Comment: This is not an _hermeneutic_ answer. It expresses an opinion and anecdotal personal experience. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.